# R Plotly: issue xref/x layout when x axis is POSIXct format

Tags: r, time-series, plotly, posixct

I have started to use Plotly library and I´m not be able to add an image via layout whe x axis is POSIXct format.

Here a reproducible example:

```
date <- seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct("2015-02-21 15:00", tz = "GMT"),   
                   to = as.POSIXct("2015-02-21 23:00", tz = "GMT"),
                   by = 3600)

set.seed(135)
temp <- runif(9, -5, 20)

df <- as.data.frame(date)

df[,'temp'] <- temp

p <- plot_ly(df, x = ~date, y= ~temp, type = "scatter", mode = "line")

p %>% layout(
  images = list(
    source = "https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/r-logo.png",
    xref = "x",
    yref = "paper",
    x = as.POSIXct("2015-02-21 18:00", tz = "GMT"),
    y = 0.5,
    sizex = 1,
    sizey = 1,
    opacity = 1
  
  )
)
```

This is the result:

[image]

As you can see in the figure the r logo is not shown. Someone could help with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40204508/r-plotly-add-a-image-in-background

Comment: Thanks for the answere, but import the image it´s not the problem. I have not problem to add an image to the plot when x axis units are not dates

Answer (score 1):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44852311/8107362), the real issue is about the size of the image. Plotly determines the size of an image on a time axis in milliseconds, so there is an image but it's really really small with `xref = "x"` and `sizex = 1`. You could have also set `xref = "paper"` to be relative to the plot layout.

```
library(plotly)
date <- seq.POSIXt(from = as.POSIXct("2015-02-21 15:00", tz = "GMT"),
                   to = as.POSIXct("2015-02-21 23:00", tz = "GMT"),
                   by =3600)

set.seed(135)
temp <- runif(9, -5, 20)

df <- as.data.frame(date)

df[, 'temp'] <- temp

p <- plotly::plot_ly(df, x = ~date, y= ~temp, type = "scatter", mode = "line")
p %>% plotly::layout(
  images = list(
    source = "https://images.plot.ly/language-icons/api-home/r-logo.png",
    xref = "x",
    yref = "paper",
    x = as.POSIXct("2015-02-21 18:00", tz = "GMT"),
    y = 1,
    # 7.2 million milliseconds (2 hours) wide 
    sizex = 7.2e6,
    sizey = 1,
    opacity = 1,
    # centered the image
    xanchor = "center"
    
  )
)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]